# change in Mysql system variable in java jdbc connection url do not take effect

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In mysql the system variable "max_connections" has value 100.
But i am trying to override this value programatically by pass key-value pair in jdbc connection string 
 as "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?maxConnections=3".
But it seems like it is not reflecting any change.
Here below I made maxConnection to 3 but still in below example I am able to create 40 connections.
Note I have not closed connection in each iteration purposely.Just to see if the key value added in jdbc connection string is taking effect.If it takes effect then it should give exception of "Too many Connections"

See below code for reference:

```
public class JDBCOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


        for(int i=1;i<=35;i++)
            {
            Connection conn = null;  
            Statement stmt = null;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database...:"+i);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?maxConnections=3", "root", "root");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            Integer id = null;
            String name = null;
            Double amount = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM emp where id=1";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt("id");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                amount = rs.getDouble("amount");
            }
            System.out.println("id-" + id);
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can set this through a connection property?

Answer (score 1):

`max_connections` is a global MySQL server variable governing the number of connections the server accepts from all programs connecting to it.

It's not a configuration string parameter, though. So, if you try to change it with a connection string, You Can't Do That™.

See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: But I read in offical documentation that we can pass mysql configuration parameters in jdbc string url.
For example..
jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root&autoReconnect=true
works.But if I pass mysql config parameters like "maxConnections","connectTimeout"
etc..in jdbc url it do not work.Like
jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?maxCOnnections=3&connectTimeout=300
SO i dont understand which all mysql config parameters are allowed in jdbc con url.
I have a requirment to manage this mysql config parameters programatically.Is it anything to do with global and session mysql variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using `set global max_connections = 200;` if you have the `SUPER` privilege.

e.g.:

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SET GLOBAL max_connections = ?")) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, 200);
    pstmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but it may be possible that `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is closing some of the connections when **conn** and/or **stmt** go out of scope.

You could try putting them outside the `for` loop:

```
        Connection conn = null;  
        Statement stmt = null; 
        for(int i=1;i<=35;i++)
        {
```

You could verify if connections are staying open by running the following MySQL command:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```